# Could not load assembly System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, .net-standard-2.0

I am working on .NET Core app + NET Standard 2 library.
This library uses EntityFrameworkCore.SQLServer.
When I added yet EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL then app during the start gives me an error:

... Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExce
ptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, C
ulture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
File name: 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
at Npgsql.NpgsqlWriteBuffer.Write[T](T value)

I have reinstalled the EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL - not fixed.
May be I can add this assembly to my library but where I can get it:
'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe, Version=4.0.4.1, C
ulture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'

Thanx.

Comment: Are you sure that all EF Core package references have the same version? Otherwise there would be errors like this

Comment: I have copied the solution to other machine, built it and run - it works.